# Magento Surcharges on cart page

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I have added a surcharge module to Magento which works as desired however on the cart page the HTML tag is

```
<th>
```

instead of

```
<td>
```

so the styling is not correct.
Does anyone know where that tag is picked up from?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look for the tag in \checkout\total\default.phtml template in your custom theme. If you will not find it there then you can enable path hints in your magento. Here is [the description of how to do it](https://support.sweettoothrewards.com/entries/21255937-How-do-I-turn-on-template-path-hints-)